# Jenkins Workflow Nodes in a Non-distributed Environment

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-workflow

I'm currently doing some experimentation with the Jenkins workflow plugin.

I think I understand the concept of a node but I'm wondering how this applies to non-distributed builds.

The environment I'm working in is just a single master box with no slaves, in this case is there any benefit from splitting the workflow script up into multiple nodes or could the whole script just be in one node?

I know the benefits of having slaves and probably will end up with an architecture like this but at the moment its just a single box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is unlikely to be any benefit to using multiple `node` steps in this environment. (The only example I can think of is to simulate the feature offered for freestyle projects by the [Heavy Job plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Heavy+Job+Plugin).)